# Writing song lyrics

Tags: poetry, lyrics

I find writing song lyrics really difficult -- maintaining a regular rhythm, making it rhyme and writing something that makes sense all at the same time.

Does anyone have any tips for how to write song lyrics? (This is not about writers block. I have the material I want to include already written. It just isn't in the form of a poem.)

Comment: While song lyrics are on-topic here, this question is extremely broad. Placing on hold for now, but can you edit this to ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 3):

99% of the time professional songwriters write the lyrics based upon the rhythm created by the melody.

There's a famous example of McCartney's Yesterday (from [wikipedia link to Yesterday by the Beatles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_(Beatles_song))):

> Upon being convinced that he had not robbed anyone of their melody,
> McCartney began writing lyrics to suit it. As Lennon and McCartney
> were known to do at the time, a substitute working lyric, titled
> "Scrambled Eggs" (the working opening verse was "Scrambled Eggs/Oh, my
> baby how I love your legs"), was used for the song until something
> more suitable was written.

So, you might first hum the melody and be guided by the rhythm of the melody and then begin to scat the words.  Finally, change the scatted words into sentences which make some sort of sense.

> be bop rat a dat tat
>
> She got a old red car
>
> laaaaa di do ta la la
>
> drives it down to L.A.

Are you hip to my poetic lyrics, cat?  :)

Comment: This is helpful up to a point. The Beatles didn't always write brilliant lyrics e.g. 'I Want to Hold Your Hand'. Also, because I want to write the music as well the lyrics have to come first.

Comment: Oh, *that's* why "Yesterday" is so bloody easy to parody. I've heard gag lyrics more often than the real ones.

Comment: I think you're right about Yesterday.  :)  But, honestly most lyrics -- especially on pop & rock songs -- are secondary.  Write the melody then jam the words in.  We just need a musical hook to get the people humming it. This helps explain hits like "Oops I did it again..." right?

Comment: @Tave I'm not sure I agree with SaberWriter that *99%* of the time the melody comes first, but if you're writing the music AND the lyrics then why must the lyrics come first?  Aside from the hyperbole, this seems like a good suggestion.  If you were writing with a collaborator who preferred to set preexisting lyrics to music you might have a problem, but in this case, just reverse your current practice (since this way isn't working for you anyway).

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - There's a bit on Jimmy Fallon's Tonight Show where (the real) Paul sings his original lyrics to the song.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I don't think the lyrics should depend on the music/melody. I am aware of several songs which have different 'tunes' for the same words. If I try, I can also sing the same lyrics to different tunes. It is not a matter of writing the melodies first. Of course this is not to suggest that the style of the melody and harmony aren't integral to the overall meaning/beauty/whatever of the whole piece.

Comment: @Tave It's not a matter of right or wrong.  The plain fact is that song is a marriage of words and melody.  A lyric without a melody is a poem, not a song.  While it's certainly possible to write lyrics before the melody, it is common to write the melody first (which would help with exactly the issues you are wrestling against).  You might also consider a collaborator --many of the world's greatest songs had a different person composing the music than the lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from SaberWriter's excellent suggestion, I can only offer the old standbys, read lots of lyrics (research), and write lots of lyrics (practice).

Writing good lyrics is notoriously difficult.  There's a reason why even many hit songs have terrible lyrics.

It's also worth noting that even many good songs end up quietly sacrificing at least one of your desired traits (good rhythm, good rhyme, sense).

Answer (score -1):

I am not a professional writer but I do have some experience in writing poetry and lyrics. Sometimes I write the lyrics and give them to somebody else to find the right melody, and sometimes I have the melody to build up the lyrics on, which is of course more difficult.

I suggest that you read lots of books with different subjects, listen to people talking about things, and let your imagination 'fly' :) It really helped me!
Sometimes I do use the 'rhyme finder'on google but with a very good imagination and a complex vocabulary everything will come together pretty easily.